# Is "float" tag cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I want to add a [float] tag to a question, but found the tag seems not exist (at least at now):

```
Are you sure you want to create new tags?

The following tags do not exist: [float].
```

I suspect it is cleaned up, because I can see other primitive types as tags such as [int], [double], [boolean] and so on. Even [long] tag, it seems become a tag synonym of [long-integer].

Is [float] tag cleaned up before?

Comment: Why would you *want* to add [float] to a question? It's a bit difficult imagining a question where using a basic-datatype-tag would be useful...

Comment: `[float]` was sent floating down the river.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it was [killed off almost two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127147/we-need-to-get-rid-of-disambiguate-the-float-tag) because it was ambiguous between two very popular technologies that had absolutely nothing to do with each other. Use [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) or [css-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-float) instead.